p.$348$ of AEC, Why we don't care infinite point of　$C_d : dW^2=d^2+DZ^4$?
In the first two lines of page $348$ of Silverman's book "The Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves," (http://www.pdmi.ras.ru/~lowdimma/BSD/Silverman-Arithmetic_of_EC.pdf), he calculates that $C_d : dW^2=d^2+DZ^4$ does not have $\mathbb{R}$-rational points because $d<0$.
However, note that $C_d$ is just an abbreviation for a projective curve. In reality, $C_d$ is a projective curve in $\mathbb{P}^3$ and $C_d : dW^2=d^2+DZ^4$ is affine part of that.
My question is, why don't we consider the infinite points of $C_d$ in its projective closure?
Indeed, page $328$ of this book says the infinite points of this curve in $\mathbb{P}^3$ are $\pm\infty:=[0,0,\pm\sqrt{\frac{-4p}{d}},1]$. When $d<0$, indeed $\pm\infty\in C_d(\mathbb{R})$. So I think the argument completely fails and the Selmer group should be larger.
However, any online sources like Magma and Sage calculate the same result as Silverman's.
Where am I missing ?

You have a sign error (as well as a factor-of-$4$ error) in translating between the notation of p. 328 and that of p. 348. To translate between these, you want to set $D=-4b$. Here $D$ is assumed to be a (positive) prime number, so the points at infinity are not defined over $\mathbb{R}$ when $d<0$.
